# Can't access USB device inside Windows Store App

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-store-apps, openni

OK, first I shall point that I am completely new to Windows Apps Development, which is good, since I am trying to develop a Windows Store App for PC to use a PrimeSense Scanner connected via USB. I have asked a more specific question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312668/primesense-scanner-with-openni-doesnt-initialize-on-windows-8).

This time I have a more generic question, which is more related to Windows Store app development. I am using VS2013 Express and compiling for Win32.

When I compile my application for VS2012 and run it as an execcutable file, I can connect to the scanner perfectly. But I can't do the same with VS2013 and running it as a Store app.

I know the device is connected and the drivers are updated and all dlls file placed in the Widnows System 32 directory. 
I have also added all Capabilities to the App Manifest and also added the following Device Capability

```
 <m2:DeviceCapability Name="usb">
  <!--OSRFX2 Device-->
  <m2:Device Id="vidpid:1d27 0609">
    <m2:Function Type="classId:ff * *" />
    <m2:Function Type="name:vendorSpecific" />
  </m2:Device>
</m2:DeviceCapability>
```

The vid and pid, obviously match the corresponding codes of the device.

One of the errors I recieve when trying to conenct to the scanner using OpenNI is:

```
Could not open to "\\?\usb#vid_1d27&pid_0609&mi_00#7&1601586a&0&0000#{c3b5f022-5a42-1980-1909-ea72095601b1}" USB Device not found
```

This error is quite frustrating since I know the device is connected. So I tend to think that there is some level os specificity on the Windows Store App side of the game that is not enabling my to connect to the device. As I said, I am compiling for Win32.

Is there a chance that the drivers will not work for a Windows Store App. Is there some extra stuff I should do inside the Windows Store App logic that I am not doing and that is necessary to connect the USB device? I am sorry, but I am completely new to Windows Store App development.

Thank you.

Comment: Please can you confirm, that your title ask for Windows store app but in the middle you say "VS2013 desktop app will not find the scanner". I am a little confused. Do you mean "VS2013 Store App will not find the scanner"?

Comment: Yes, I meant "VS2013 Store App". Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that from metro apps.

You typically create a handle to that usb device by calling CreateFile with that [object mananger path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_%28Windows%29) as the file to 'create'. [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is [not allowed](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/05/03/win32-and-metrocreatefile2/) in metro apps - "desktop apps only" - and its 'replacement', CreateFile2, specifically doesn't allow opening object manager objects.

> Furthermore, the documentation for CreateFile2 states that in metro apps this function can only open files and directories (and not things like pipes, mailslots, consoles, etc.).

See also [this post on social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/29c363f4-9873-4890-9379-22e5b4f73f6f/opening-hid-device-stream-from-a-metroapp-createfile2-failed-?forum=tailoringappsfordevices)

Unless I missed something, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Ok I suppose it's not possible to do that by now... Hope there's a change in the future. thanks

Comment: @MobileCushion - Unfortunately, I don't think this is scheduled to change. Microsoft's model with the metro / windows store apps is a more restricted, 'safer' model. There is potentially one workaround - if you're allowed to install a desktop program along side your metro app, you could have the desktop program handle shuttling data to the usb device from your metro app. But I don't know how you'd distribute that.